# How to fill DockPanel With one control

Tags: c#, xaml, dockpanel

I am tring to have a gridview fill a dockpanel. I have LastChildFill="True" but it still doesnt fill the window. I have a grid on top that holds a label and textbox. Then a dockpanel that I want to fill the rest of the space. and then insode that dock panel, i want the Gridview to fill that space.
Heres what I have:

```
<Window x:Class="DocumentHandlingTouch.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MultitouchHOL" Height="394" Width="633" WindowState="Maximized"
    xmlns:mt="clr-namespace:DocumentHandlingTouch" Icon="/DocumentHandlingTouch;component/1414781821_143818.ico">
    <Canvas Name="_canvas">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Replace with your UserControl -->
            <Label Canvas.Left="221" Canvas.Top="0" Content="Item #" Height="28" Name="label1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox  Name="TxtItemNumber" Width="220" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFF5F5CC" />
        </Grid>
        <DockPanel Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="34" Name="dockPanel1" LastChildFill="True">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="DGVImages"  SelectionChanged="DGVImages_SelectionChanged" Height="324" Width="612" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe better just replace your `DockPanel` with `Grid`. Then put your `DataGrid` in the center of this grid. Set height and width to auto for `DataGrid`. And I think it would be what you want.